# php , You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I face this problem i don't how to solve it 
when i try to add info into my database this error appear

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$db=mysqli_select_db($con,'healthy_db');
if ($con) {
echo "good  ";
}else {
die('error');
}

$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `healthy_db`.`fitness` (id,workout_date,first_meal,second_meal) values (null,'2/12/2016','sweet','cake')");
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo "insert";
    } else {
        echo "error" .$sql ."<br>". mysqli_error($con);
        }
?>
```

Comment: change '2/12/2016' to '2016-12-02' and try

Comment: Can you try to set your field on auto increment and try your query in something like PHPMyAdmin for troubleshooting.

Comment: Either the actual query you are passing is different, the string has invisible characters, or the table has a complex trigger.  There is nothing obviously wrong with the SQL statement.

Comment: change to if ($sql) { you have already set up the query so you just need it executing.

Comment: If it is solved, pick the answer and fix the title.

Comment: @johnny: what do you mean by "fix the title"? We explicitly discourage adding [solved] title hacks here, in case that is what you meant.

Comment: @halfer I mean change it so it doesn't say solved because it's not right here on SO.  Just put the question and select the best answer.

Comment: Ah right @johnny, thanks, and yes I agree! I have fixed it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see in your code there were two issues. The $sql variable already sets up your query using your connection so you don't need run the query in the if block, and secondly (Assuming its an auto increment id which it probably should and will be) then you dont need to name it and try to populate it.

There are a few ways to solve the auto increment part.

Columns specified: (id,col1,col2) VALUES ('','data', 'moredata') or (col1,col2) VALUES ('data', 'moredata')
This type allows you to select just the columns that require the data for the query to run.

Columns Unspecified: INSERT INTO table VALUES ('', 'data', 'moredata')
This type attempts to write data to all columns so the column count in the query needs to match the column count in the table.

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db=mysqli_select_db($con,'healthy_db');
    if ($con) {
       echo "good  ";
    } else {
       die('error');
    }

    /*
     * I noted something else that may give a syntax error
     * column names need encapsulating. backticks are prefered.
     * See change i've also changed the code slightly to make it 
     * easier for you to see whats going on.
     *
     * Also Incorporating the answer below about the date format
     * to make the accepted answer more complete.
    */       

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `healthy_db`.`fitness` (`workout_date`, `first_meal`, `second_meal`) VALUES ('2016-12-2','sweet','cake')";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if ($result){
        echo "insert";
    } else {
        echo "error" .$sql ."<br>". mysqli_error($con);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the id is not null in your database  you may get this error take off the id and its value and make sure to make it auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is primary key then you can not set it as `null`.Another error is you using `mysqli_query` two times.Try below..`id`will be automatically incremented if it is `pk`.

```
$sql ="INSERT INTO fitness (workout_date,first_meal,second_meal) values ('2016-12-02','sweet','cake')";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo "insert";
    } else {
        echo "error" .$sql ."<br>". mysqli_error($con);
        }
?>
```

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  If you read the MySQL documentation, you will find this line about auto-increment ids:  "it is also possible to assign NULL to the column to generate sequence numbers.".

Comment: @GordonLinoff : Above answer is right. Because he already mentionend that "id" is  primary key and auto increment. And Primary key means "not null" and "Unique".

Comment: @Lakhan . . . You can pass a `NULL` value to the `insert`.  I guess you are *technically* correct that the value doesn't become `NULL`.  But that is the point of my comment.  If a `NULL` value is passed in, then the auto-increment value is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Replace it :

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `healthy_db`.`fitness` (id,workout_date,first_meal,second_meal) values (null,'2/12/2016','sweet','cake')");
```

With :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `healthy_db`.`fitness` (workout_date,first_meal,second_meal) values ('2/12/2016','sweet','cake')";
```